# ssh to a qemu virtual machine guest without typing in the password

Tags: ssh, passwords, qemu

Now I want to run a script from a client machine which will ssh to a virtual machine guest on a host machine and start to run a shell command. I do not want to be prompted to input the password.

So firstly I try to do it to connect to the host. I copy the file id_rsa.pub in the .ssh folder from the client to the host's file called authorized_keys in the .ssh folder. Then when I 
"ssh root@hostname"
It works fine and I do not need to input the password(note my client's account is not root).

Then I try the same thing to the virtual machine guest in the host. I copied the same file to the guest. I started the guest  using qemu with option "-net user,vlan=0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22 " which will forward the requests to host 5555 port to guest's 22 port. Then in the client, I executed
" ssh -p 5555 root@hostname "
It fails. It shows that RSA key for the host has changed or something... Note that my guest's account is also root and I can use Putty to ssh to the guest by  connecting to the  5555 port of the host. And I believe the file permission is also properly handled.

Does anyone have a clue :>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is correct behavior.

When you get connected to the host system first time, the ssh at your client machine ask you if the machine with fingerprint bla-bla-bla really the one you are  wanted to connect. You replied 'yes' and ssh at your client machine memorized the host name, IP and the fingerprint in the file ~/.ssh/known_hosts. Then during all subsequent connections it verifies that the fingerprint is not changed as a change is an indication that the authentication process requires your attention. There could be a few valid reasons of a mismatch:

- you re-installed sshd at the remote host;
- your host uses DHCP to get its IP and the IP got changed.

The case when you know precisely that the fingerprint should not change indicates to you an attempt to make you get into another system.

This mechanism aimed to make you sure that you are logged in to the system you are expected to log in.

In your case you first log into the system at IP a.b.c.d at port 22. Then you try to log in with the same IP a.b.c.d at port 5555. There is your VM behind this port that is having different fingerprint. So ssh complains.

The solution for your problem will be to log in to the host system and then from this remote shell session into VM. Also I would recommend you to generate another pair of public/private keys for this 'remote' connection. Thus when your private key kept at the host get compromised then your private key that is kept at your workstation remains valid.

Comment: @ Serge  Hi, thank your very much for the reply. It makes sense. So the fingerprint is with ip ,regardless of the port?:< But I am not quite understand what you mean by saying "and then from this remote shell session into VM". I want to write a script in the client machine doing this automatically(ideally without any human interaction). Can you provide more details :>

Comment: Yes, regardless of the port. "But I am not quite..." You log into the host system and you type `ssh your-vm-address` command at remote system's shell command prompt. As for automation of the process try at your workstation this command: `ssh root@your-remotehost 'ssh your-vm-address'`